# Inferential logic in a simple-life situation.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Here's a little situation I want math to resolve for me :

1. If I study, I make the exam ,
2. If I do not play tennis, I study ,
3. I didn't make the exam

Can I conclude that was playing tennis ?

Trying to put this into the symbology of inference logic and propositional classic logic :

$P1 : \text{study} \implies \text{exam}$

$P2 : (\text{tennis}\, \vee \text{study}) \wedge (\neg \text{tennis} \implies \text{study})$  (disjunctive syllogism)

$p3 : \neg \text{exam}$

My reasoning :

**Step 1** : the contrapositive of $P1$ is $P1' : \neg \text{exam} \implies \neg \text{study}$ ;

**Step 2** : By Modus Tollens ( $ [(P \implies Q) \wedge \neg Q] \implies \neg P$)  we have : $(\text{study} \implies \text{exam}) \wedge (\neg \text{exam} \implies \neg \text{study})$

**Step 3** : should we suppose : $\neg \text{tennis} \wedge \neg \text{study}$, then $\neg ( \text{tennis} \vee  \text{study})$, then (by $P2$) $\text{tennis}$ or otherwise the $P1$ would fall since $\neg \text{study}$ and $\neg (False \implies False)$.

**Step 4** : reductio ad absurdum from step $(3)$, we have $(\text{tennis} \vee \text{study})$, henceforth, in $P2$, $\neg \text{tennis}$ or else $false \implies false$.

So, have I been playing tennis or is my inferential logic bad ?

Comment: The title should be more informative.

Comment: Would the person that "minused" the question care to say why ? That would be nice !

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: I am not accusing either, and I've just asked the question to see what I can avoid next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, we can easily arrive at the conclusion that you played tennis: and the repeated use of modus tollens, alone (plus one invocation of double negation) gets you that conclusion.

Our premises, in "natural language":

```
1. If I study, I make the exam ,
2. If I do not play tennis, I study ,
3. I didn't make the exam
```

---

KEY:

$S:\; $ I study.

$E:\; $ I make the exam.

$P:\; $ I play tennis.

---

Then our premises translate to:

$(1): S \rightarrow E$.

$(2): \lnot P \rightarrow S.$

$(3): \lnot E.$

---

$(4)\quad  \lnot S$ follows from $(1), (3)$ by modus tollens.

$(5)\quad  \lnot \lnot P$ follows from $(2), (4)$ by modus tollens.

$\therefore (6) \quad  P$, by $(5)$ and double negation.

Hence you can conclude you played tennis.

Comment: As @Matt Brenneman did, you translated the second statement to : $\neg P \implies S$ while I've translated it to : $(P \vee S) \wedge \neg S \implies P$, which I thought was safer. Admitting your translation, I would totally agree with your reasoning, but admitting mine, would we come still to the conclusion that I play tennis ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely you would! $\lnot P \rightarrow S \equiv \lnot \lnot P \lor S\equiv P \lor S$. Then since we have $\lnot S$, too, you can conclude $P$.

Comment: I know you love logic and for this reason this answer is excellent;-)+1

Comment: @amWhy : thank you, now it's clear !

Comment: You're welcome, @Gloserio!

Comment: @Gloserio There are a number of different ways to prove this (as you can see), but IMO, there is a difference between "formal logic" and what you use in everyday practical mathematics. FWIW, and I'm a grad student in math, I've never used anything beyond 3 simple rules in doing mathematical proofs: modus ponens, the fact that a statement is logically equivalent to its contrapositive, and that the negation of p implies q is (~p or q). I think these 3 facts form the basis of the vast majority of proofs you do, and so IMO, are more useful to understand and to work with.

Comment: @MattBrenneman : do you suggest we use inferential logic with a bit more freedom than we would use strict logic ?

Comment: @Gloserio  I'm not quite sure I understand your question. The arguments w/ ad w/o modus tollens are both rigorous; they just use different (yet logically equivalent) forms of the given statements. My previous comment was just my opinion that the 3 forms I alluded to earlier are more useful when you do mathematical proofs (which is why I used them). This is my opinion, but it is based on the fact these are the methods I see most commonly used in mathematical proofs I do everyday. In one sense it is not a big deal, but if you want to learn how to do math proofs, it's something to consider.

Comment: @amWhy: Right down your alley! +1

Comment: @MattBrenneman : ok I get it now, thank you :)

Comment: @Gloserio  You're very welcome. Logic is a lot of fun and I hope you enjoy you're continued studies!

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your step 3, because considering only P2, the term $\neg ( tennis \vee  study)$ does not imply $tennis \vee study$.

This may sound counter-intuitive to your introduction.

The reason is, that your P2 is an arguable translation of statement 2. It is not equivalent to "if I don't play tennis, I study". Rather it states "if I don't play tennis and if I study, I study", which is a tautology. You can see this by drawing a truth-table for P2.

Also note that $\neg exam, \neg tennis, \neg study$ satisfies P1,P2 and P3.

So I would replace P2 by $$\neg tennis \rightarrow study.$$ This also repairs your Step3.

Comment: +1, you're probably true, that why I've asked this question, because I felt as if my $P2$ was somewhat redundant. Thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It just reduces down to look at the contrapositives of your statements.
Statement 1 is logically equivalent to : ~(make exam) implies ~study. 
Statement 2 is logically equivalent to: ~study implies (play tennis).
So the truth of ~(make exam) directly implies you played tennis (use *modus ponens* twice).

Comment: How is second statement logically equivalent to $\neg study \implies tennis$ ?

Comment: It is the contrapositive of the statement: "~(play tennis) implies study"

Comment: So how that you converted natural langage to logic symobols, and in its valid.